# Search all pascal camel-case words in .ts files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to use a regular expression in the Search panel in Visual Studio Code. In my particular case, I need to find all Pascal Camel-case words in *.ts files.

I use `\b([A-Z0-9][a-z0-9]+)*` regex and the result is not what I expect:

This is what I get:

[image: The result]

This is what I expect:

[image: The expectation]

It looks like I use Search panel in a wrong way or it doesn't work properly.

Any bits of advice, folks?

**UPD:**
Correct regular expression `\b([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)\w+`

Comment: This is what did I get so far: `Match Case` and `Match Whole Word` options should be selected. It looks better, but the results list is full of duplicates and unnecessary lines.

Comment: `\b([A-Z])\w+` and click the `match case` option on the find panel.

Comment: Hi @Mark
It seems your advice is a solution, except of regex -- it doesn't meet the requirement. Should be `\b([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)\w+`
Thank you